# Trouble with adding UILabel to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I have some trouble with adding UILabel as subview to UITableViewCell. My code:

```
bookMarkTable=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 480, 270)];
    bookMarkTable.rowHeight = 38.0f;
    bookMarkTable.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:247/255.0 green:246/255.0 blue:242/255.0 alpha:1];
    [bookMarkTable setDelegate:self];
    [bookMarkTable setDataSource:self];
    [bookMarkMainView addSubview:bookMarkTable];
```

and UITableView delegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return bookMarksArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    // Configure the cell...

    NSMutableDictionary* cellDictionary =[bookMarksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel* bookMarkTitle =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 370, 40)];
    bookMarkTitle.text=[cellDictionary valueForKey:@"bm_title"];
    bookMarkTitle.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    bookMarkTitle.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:20.0f];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:bookMarkTitle];
    return cell;

}
- (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath{
    return 38.0f;
}
```

I add rows via this method

```
-(void)addBookmark{
    NSMutableDictionary* infoDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    NSString* bookmarkTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is :[%i]",bookMarksArray.count];
    [infoDict setValue:bookmarkTitle forKey:@"bm_title"];
    [bookMarksArray addObject:infoDict];
    [bookMarkTable reloadData];

}
```

But when i invoke this method multiply times it seems that all UILabel are added more than once. Here is a result [image: result]

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that each time you move the table, the method is called and adds a new `UILabel` to the cell.

You should create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and add the label there.
Other option, since you are just using one label, is to use the default label of UITableViewCell.

Change

```
UILabel* bookMarkTitle =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 370, 40)];
bookMarkTitle.text=[cellDictionary valueForKey:@"bm_title"];
bookMarkTitle.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
bookMarkTitle.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:20.0f];
[cell.contentView addSubview:bookMarkTitle];
```

to

```
cell.textLabel.text = [cellDictionary valueForKey:@"bm_title"];
```

Answer (score 0):

At the begin from `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you must remove the subviews.

```
for(UIView* vista in cell.contentView){
    [vista removeFromSuperview];
}
```

And that's all.

PD: Check if the removed view is the correct.

Answer (score -4):

Try to change:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

with:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
```

Comment: Although this will work, but its not efficient, since IOS will be creating a new cell everytime and not reuse it. You should actually look at the other 2 answers, which are probably more efficient, esp I think you should be subclassing UITableViewCell and add label as a property in that class, and setup 'non-changing' properties of that cell (e.g. background color) as part of init method.

Comment: @AC1 I have 3 another subviews, so i don't think it will be efficient to remove them all the time.

Comment: that's why probably its best to subclass it and "pre-add" your subviews in your class, so that you don't have to create and add them for each cell, since the cells will be reused. In this selected answer, the cells will not be reused and you'll be creating and adding your subviews for each cell.